# Convert invalid JSON string with single or no quotes

Tags: c#, json, regex

I have an invalid json string like,

```
"{StateName: { before: 'AA',  after: 'AAA'} },"
```

Can anyone please help with Regex expression to replace invalid string with valid JSON data? I need to skip the comma at the end & replace single quotes with double quotes or add double quotes where its missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arti I have tried doing this way for a single property value like 
string str = "{StateName: { before: 'AA',  after: 'AAA'} },"
Regex.Replace(str, @"(^|\s)before:(\s|$)", "\"before\":");

Comment: @Arti, So I wanted to know if there is any way that if its possible to do the multiple invalid string replace.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Replace()

```
jsonString = jsonString.Replace("'", "\"");
jsonString = jsonString.Replace("},", "}");
```

Comment: what about in condition where there is missing double quotes in property name? Like in this case **StateName**

Answer (score 0):

Simply you use DeserializeObject() on your json string

```
string json = "{\"StateName\": { "\before\": "\AA\",  "\after\": "\AAA\"} }";
```

and then

```
object jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json.ToString());
```

Comment: The string I have is not in valid JSON format. So I cant use  DeserializeObject()

Comment: I believe as @princeofmince suggests
if you StateName is static then you can 
jsonString = jsonString.Replace("StateName", "\"StateName\"");

but if wonder how would you handle this type of response string as json ?